# In Android how do I make an image appear without using findViewByID?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an image appear in an if statement But it does not like findviewbyId so is there any other way to display the image - error says cannot be resolved to a variable

```
    public boolean play(int column){
    for (int r = 0; r <= 5;r++){
        if (getState(column, r) == State.BLANK){
            if (player1Turn == true){
                count[column][r] = State.RED;               
                //image
                ImageView redCounter = (ImageView) findViewById.(R.id.redCounter);

                //end
            }else {
```

Comment: `it does not like findviewbyId` - what do you mean by that?

Comment: gives this error  cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your code is the dot (.) after `findViewById.`

```
ImageView redCounter = (ImageView) findViewById.(R.id.redCounter);
```

remove it to be like that

```
ImageView redCounter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.redCounter);
```